# passing security headers to soap envelop from wsdl

Tags: oracle, soap, plsql

I am calling a SOAP Service from PLSQL I have this [wsld](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14WDMc-CyvppA3rqfi19_aTIsXvdTQYUB/view?usp=sharing)  for soap service. I have below SOAP envelop to call from PLSQL

```
 <soapenv:Body><cus:SaveSales><!--Optional:--><cus:salesRequestENDataContract><cus1:Subcontractor>
    <cus1:CompanyCode>75</cus1:CompanyCode><cus1:RegionCode>98</cus1:RegionCode><cus1:StoreCode>UMT41</cus1:StoreCode>
    <cus1:CashTillCode>1</cus1:CashTillCode><cus1:CashierCode>'||FETCH_HEADER.CASH_NAT_ID||'</cus1:CashierCode></cus1:Subcontractor>
    <cus1:SalesDate><cus1:Day>'||FETCH_HEADER.GUN||'</cus1:Day><cus1:Month>'||FETCH_HEADER.AY||'</cus1:Month><cus1:Year>'||FETCH_HEADER.YIL||'</cus1:Year>
    <cus1:Hour>'||FETCH_HEADER.SAAT||'</cus1:Hour><cus1:Minute>'||FETCH_HEADER.DAKIKA||'</cus1:Minute><cus1:Second>'||FETCH_HEADER.SANIYE||'</cus1:Second>
    </cus1:SalesDate><!--Optional:--><cus1:InvoiceNumber>'||FETCH_HEADER.DOC_PROV_NO||'</cus1:InvoiceNumber><cus1:Customer>
    <cus1:IdentityType>'||FETCH_HEADER.DOC_TYPE||'</cus1:IdentityType><cus1:PassportNo>'||FETCH_HEADER.PASSPORT_NO||'</cus1:PassportNo>
    <cus1:CustomerName>'||FETCH_HEADER.PASS_SUR_NAME||'</cus1:CustomerName><cus1:DateOfBirth>
    <cus1:Day>'||TO_CHAR(FETCH_HEADER.PAS_DOB,'DD')||'</cus1:Day><cus1:Month>'||TO_CHAR(FETCH_HEADER.PAS_DOB,'MM')||'</cus1:Month>
    <cus1:Year>'||TO_CHAR(FETCH_HEADER.PAS_DOB,'YYYY')||'</cus1:Year><cus1:Hour>0</cus1:Hour><cus1:Minute>0</cus1:Minute>
    <cus1:Second>0</cus1:Second></cus1:DateOfBirth><cus1:PassengerTypeCode>'||FETCH_HEADER.PASSENGER_TYPE||'</cus1:PassengerTypeCode>
    <cus1:Arrival_Departure_Code>2</cus1:Arrival_Departure_Code></cus1:Customer><cus1:SalesLine><!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
    <cus1:SalesLine><cus1:ProductGroupCode>99</cus1:ProductGroupCode><cus1:SalesQuantity>'||FETCH_HEADER.SUM_QTY||'</cus1:SalesQuantity>
    <cus1:LimitUnitQuantity>'||FETCH_HEADER.SUM_QTY||'</cus1:LimitUnitQuantity><!--Optional:--><cus1:DolarAmount>'||FETCH_HEADER.TENDER_AMOUNT*1.12||'</cus1:DolarAmount>
    <!--Optional:--><cus1:EuroAmount>'||FETCH_HEADER.TENDER_AMOUNT||'</cus1:EuroAmount></cus1:SalesLine></cus1:SalesLine></cus:salesRequestENDataContract>
    </cus:SaveSales></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

When I call the SOAP service from PLSQ it Give me below Error

```
Response> content-length: "1743" Response> status_code: "500" Response> reason_phrase: "Internal Server Error" Response> http_version: "HTTP/1.1" Response> length: "347" === Print first 1000 lines of HTTP response... === [00]: <s:Envelope xmlns:s="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/… xmlns:a="docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/… xml:lang="en-US">An error occurred when verifying security for the message.</faultstring></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

So it Maybe or maybe not due to security headers included to SOAP envelop but i dont know how to get these header from WSDL as attached. Please see below sample headers also and guide how to append with Envelop

```
<soapenv:Header>
      <wsu:Security xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <sp:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-7" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/...tility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:Username>110001234</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/...0#PasswordText">1AB2C3DEF45G6A78</wsse:Password>
         </sp:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
      <ser:Profile>
         <ser:Name>1.0</ser:Name>
         <ser:Client>MyAdaptorName</ser:Client>
         <ser:Adapter>Adaptor</ser:Adapter>
         <ser:Machine>MyServer</ser:Machine>
      </ser:Profile>
   </soapenv:Header>
```

I want to get resolved this by adding headers or something else as suggestion to catch and resolve the error.

**Update**

```
PROCEDURE SALES_XML_CUSTOMS_PRC
   IS

  v_len number;

    l_http_request   UTL_HTTP.req;
    l_http_response  UTL_HTTP.resp;
    l_buffer_size    NUMBER(10) := 30000;
    l_line_size      NUMBER(10) := 20000;
    l_lines_count    NUMBER(10) := 1000;
    l_string_request VARCHAR2(32767);
    l_line           VARCHAR2(30000);
    l_substring_msg  VARCHAR2(30000);
    l_raw_data       RAW(30000);
    l_clob_response  CLOB;
--    l_host_name      VARCHAR2(128) := '195.128.37.14';
    l_host_name      VARCHAR2(128) := 'inatestgumrukws.unifree.com.tr';
    l_port           VARCHAR2(128) := '443'; --80: http, 443: https
    l_resp_xml        XMLType;
    l_result_XML_node VARCHAR2(128);
    l_NAMESPACE_SOAP  VARCHAR2(128) := 'xmlns:ns0=''urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions''';
    l_response_Customername   VARCHAR2(128);
    l_response_Cardname   VARCHAR2(128);
    l_response_points   number;
    L_AMOUNT  NUMBER;
    data varchar2(32767);
    name  VARCHAR2(256);
    value VARCHAR2(1024);
    i number;

    l_nonce_raw   RAW (100);
    l_nonce_b64   VARCHAR2 (100);
    l_timestamp_char VARCHAR2(100)  := TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"');
    --'https://inatestgumrukws.unifree.com.tr/Services/CustomService.svc',
  BEGIN
    l_nonce_raw := UTL_I18N.string_to_raw (DBMS_RANDOM.string ('a', 16), 'utf8');
    l_nonce_b64 := TL_I18N.raw_to_char (UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode (l_nonce_raw), 'utf8');

    UTL_HTTP.SET_WALLET('file:/oracle/Certs/wallet', 'aiadmin123');
        --  show_html_from_url('https://inatestgumrukws.unifree.com.tr/Services/CustomService.svc');

  FOR FETCH_HEADER IN GET_HEADER LOOP 
  l_string_request := '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cus="https://unifree.com.tr/services/custom" xmlns:cus1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CustomServiceLibrary.DataContract">

   <soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" 
      xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
      xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-ABF79B0979E24BB376155515304061026" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-13">
      <wsse:Username>75</wsse:Username>
      <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">Test357</wsse:Password>
      <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">'||l_nonce_b64||'</wsse:Nonce>
      <wsu:Created>'||l_timestamp_char||'</wsu:Created>
      </wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>

   <soapenv:Body><cus:SaveSales><!--Optional:-->
    <cus:salesRequestENDataContract><cus1:Subcontractor>
    <cus1:CompanyCode>75</cus1:CompanyCode><cus1:RegionCode>98</cus1:RegionCode><cus1:StoreCode>UMT41</cus1:StoreCode>
    <cus1:CashTillCode>1</cus1:CashTillCode><cus1:CashierCode>'||FETCH_HEADER.CASH_NAT_ID||'</cus1:CashierCode></cus1:Subcontractor>
    <cus1:SalesDate><cus1:Day>'||FETCH_HEADER.GUN||'</cus1:Day><cus1:Month>'||FETCH_HEADER.AY||'</cus1:Month><cus1:Year>'||FETCH_HEADER.YIL||'</cus1:Year>
    <cus1:Hour>'||FETCH_HEADER.SAAT||'</cus1:Hour><cus1:Minute>'||FETCH_HEADER.DAKIKA||'</cus1:Minute><cus1:Second>'||FETCH_HEADER.SANIYE||'</cus1:Second>
    </cus1:SalesDate><!--Optional:--><cus1:InvoiceNumber>'||FETCH_HEADER.DOC_PROV_NO||'</cus1:InvoiceNumber><cus1:Customer>
    <cus1:IdentityType>'||FETCH_HEADER.DOC_TYPE||'</cus1:IdentityType><cus1:PassportNo>'||FETCH_HEADER.PASSPORT_NO||'</cus1:PassportNo>
    <cus1:CustomerName>'||FETCH_HEADER.PASS_SUR_NAME||'</cus1:CustomerName><cus1:DateOfBirth>
    <cus1:Day>'||TO_CHAR(FETCH_HEADER.PAS_DOB,'DD')||'</cus1:Day><cus1:Month>'||TO_CHAR(FETCH_HEADER.PAS_DOB,'MM')||'</cus1:Month>
    <cus1:Year>'||TO_CHAR(FETCH_HEADER.PAS_DOB,'YYYY')||'</cus1:Year><cus1:Hour>0</cus1:Hour><cus1:Minute>0</cus1:Minute>
    <cus1:Second>0</cus1:Second></cus1:DateOfBirth><cus1:PassengerTypeCode>'||FETCH_HEADER.PASSENGER_TYPE||'</cus1:PassengerTypeCode>
    <cus1:Arrival_Departure_Code>2</cus1:Arrival_Departure_Code></cus1:Customer><cus1:SalesLine><!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
    <cus1:SalesLine><cus1:ProductGroupCode>99</cus1:ProductGroupCode><cus1:SalesQuantity>'||FETCH_HEADER.SUM_QTY||'</cus1:SalesQuantity>
    <cus1:LimitUnitQuantity>'||FETCH_HEADER.SUM_QTY||'</cus1:LimitUnitQuantity><!--Optional:--><cus1:DolarAmount>'||FETCH_HEADER.TENDER_AMOUNT*1.12||'</cus1:DolarAmount>
    <!--Optional:--><cus1:EuroAmount>'||FETCH_HEADER.TENDER_AMOUNT||'</cus1:EuroAmount></cus1:SalesLine></cus1:SalesLine></cus:salesRequestENDataContract>
    </cus:SaveSales></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>';

   UTL_HTTP.set_response_error_check (TRUE);
   UTL_HTTP.set_detailed_excp_support (TRUE);
   UTL_HTTP.set_cookie_support (TRUE);
   UTL_HTTP.set_follow_redirect (3);
   UTL_HTTP.set_persistent_conn_support (TRUE);
   UTL_HTTP.SET_TRANSFER_TIMEOUT(200);

   l_http_request :=  UTL_HTTP.begin_request ('https://inatestgumrukws.unifree.com.tr/Services/CustomService.svc', 'POST', UTL_HTTP.HTTP_VERSION_1_1);

    --UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(l_http_request, 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)');
    UTL_HTTP.SET_HEADER(l_http_request, 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0');
  --  UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'Host', l_host_name || ':' || l_port);
    --UTL_HTTP.set_authentication(l_http_request,'75','Test357');
   -- UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'Connection', 'close');
    UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');
    UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'SOAPAction', 'https://unifree.com.tr/services/custom/ICustomServiceEN/SaveSales');
    UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Length', LENGTH(l_string_request));
    UTL_HTTP.write_text(l_http_request, l_string_request);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Request>' || l_string_request || '');

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Response> content-length: "' || LENGTH(l_string_request) || '"');

  <<request_loop>>
    FOR i IN 0..CEIL(LENGTH(l_string_request) / l_buffer_size) - 1 LOOP

        l_substring_msg := SUBSTR(l_string_request, i * l_buffer_size + 1, l_buffer_size);

        BEGIN
            l_raw_data := utl_raw.cast_to_raw(l_substring_msg);
            UTL_HTTP.write_raw(r => l_http_request, data => l_raw_data);
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                    EXIT request_loop;
        END;
    END LOOP request_loop;


    l_http_response := UTL_HTTP.get_response(l_http_request);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Response> status_code: "' || l_http_response.status_code || '"');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Response> reason_phrase: "' ||l_http_response.reason_phrase || '"');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Response> http_version: "' ||l_http_response.http_version || '"');


    IF l_http_response.status_code = '200' AND l_http_response.reason_phrase = 'OK' THEN
            --null;
    UPDATE OFF_SENT_SALES@MOSIAT
    SET SENT_FLAG = 9
    WHERE SALE_REF_NO = FETCH_HEADER.SALE_REF_NO
    AND DOC_PROV_NO = FETCH_HEADER.TRANSNUMBER;

    END IF;

   BEGIN

        <<response_loop>>
        LOOP
            UTL_HTTP.read_raw(l_http_response, l_raw_data, l_buffer_size);
            l_clob_response := l_clob_response || UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(l_raw_data);
        END LOOP response_loop;

        EXCEPTION
            WHEN UTL_HTTP.end_of_body THEN
                UTL_HTTP.end_response(l_http_response);
    END;    


    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Response> length: "' || LENGTH(l_clob_response) || '"');
   -- DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Response> ' || (l_clob_response) || '"');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(CHR(10) || '=== Print first ' || l_lines_count || ' lines of HTTP response... ===' || CHR(10) || CHR(10));


    FOR i IN 0..CEIL(LENGTH(l_clob_response) / l_line_size) - 1 LOOP
        l_line := SUBSTR(l_clob_response, i * l_line_size + 1, l_line_size);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('[' || LPAD(i, 2, '0') || ']: ' || l_line);
        EXIT WHEN i > l_lines_count - 1;
    END LOOP print_response;


  IF l_http_request.private_hndl IS NOT NULL THEN
        UTL_HTTP.end_request(l_http_request);
    END IF;

    IF l_http_response.private_hndl IS NOT NULL THEN
        UTL_HTTP.end_response(l_http_response);
    END IF;

    end loop;


    UTL_HTTP.end_response(l_http_response);

      commit;


   END   SALES_XML_CUSTOMS_PRC;
```

I am Getting all the time below error

```
5:26:00 PM  ORA-29269: HTTP server error 500 - Internal Server Error
5:26:00 PM  ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1367
5:26:00 PM  ORA-06512: at "INVSPROD.SALES_XML_CUSTOMS_PRC_5", line 155
5:26:00 PM  ORA-06512: at line 7
```

Comment: Where is your PLSQL code? Your example envelope is not valid XML, it's missing the `<soapenv:Envelope>` tag. Normally the Header comes after the Envelope tag and before the Body tag.

Comment: Please see the update

Comment: Are you getting DBMS Output from this procedure? Or just error?

Comment: Just getting Error when i run this

Comment: What is `GET_HEADER`? It doesn't seem like that loop is running.

Comment: This is Cursor declared above the query was too long so i didnt mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You can add UserToken header with the commercial [ORA_XML](https://www.didisoft.com/ora-rsa/tutorial/soap/#user) package:

```
DECLARE
  encode_password BOOLEAN; 
  signed_soap CLOB;
  soap_data CLOB;
BEGIN
    soap_data := '...';
 
    encode_password := FALSE; 
 
    signed_soap := ORA_XML.SOAP_WSS_USERNAME_SIGN(soap_data, 'user', 'pass', encode_password);
 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('signed_data=' || signed_soap);
END;
```

Disclaimer: I work for DidiSoft